# What do the state features of KukaGymEnv represent?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ddpg, hindsight-experience-replay, state-spaces, pybullet

I trying to use DDPG augmented with Hindsight Experience Replay (HER) on [pybullet's KukaGymEnv](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/gym/pybullet_envs/bullet/kukaGymEnv.py).

To formulate the feature vector for the goal state, I need to know what the features of the state of the environment represent. To be precise, a typical state vector of KukaGymEnv is an object of the `numpy.ndarray` class with a shape of `(9,)`.

What do each of these 8 elements represent, and how can I formulate the goal state vector for this environment? I tried going through the [source code](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/gym/pybullet_envs/bullet/kukaGymEnv.py) of the KukaGymEnv, but was unable to understand anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an incomplete answer, but it may help.

Your state is read by the function `getExtendedObservation()`. This function makes two things : it calls the function `getObservation()` from [this source code](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/gym/pybullet_envs/bullet/kuka.py), gets a state, and extend this state with three components :

> relative x,y position and euler angle of block in gripper space

But what are the 5 first components returned by `getObservation()`? From what I read, there are positions, then euler angles describing the orientation. But that would make 6 + 3 = 9 features, so there is either only 2 positions, or only 2 euler angles. You may know kuka better than me and know the answer of this one :).

So, to sum up :

```
state = [X, Y, (Z, ) , Alpha, Gamma, (Beta, ), gripX, gripY, gripAlpha]
```

(Either Z or Beta is absent)

Comment: There's a mistake in the question. The state space for the environment is actually a 9 dimensional vector, in which case, your answer is correct. I ll rectify the typo right away. Thanks for the help!